# My FindGameObjectWithTag becomes null and game was stop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i have a short code to let my Enemy chasing my Player, but when my Player got destroy, my game just stop because Enemy can't find a target, how can i fix this. here is my code.
My Player Script:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
```

my Enemy Script:

```
private void Start()
    {
        speed = startSpeed;
        health = startHealth;
        fireCountdown = 3f;
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        target = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Transform>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (target != null)
        {
            transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else
        {
            transform.position += transform.right * -1 * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
```

Comment: I'd break your statement assigning into `target` into two steps. First try to find the player, then if it isn't null assign the target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for your Update method:

```
    private void Update()
    {
        if (target != null)
        {
            transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else
        {
            transform.position += transform.right * -1 * speed * Time.deltaTime;
            var player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
            if (player != null) target = player.transform;
        }
}
```

This is presuming you have respawned the player in another script so the game can continue.

Comment: well, it still get this "object reference not set to an instance of an object unity" because, my Player got destroy already, so the Enemy script can't find gameobjectwith tag, then the game got error

Comment: alright it works, i'm so silly, btw can you explain to me why i have to put 
var player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player"); in Else statement ? i guess update do every frame so the next update, target will be exactly what i put in else statement, right ?

Comment: Yes, that's right. If there is no player on that frame, it will try again next frame until the player exists again. If you're happy with the answer, please mark it correct and upvote!